# Spring boot 2.0 and Spring Cloud Sleuth 2.x Working Sample

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have been trying to get Spring boot 2.0 and Spring Cloud Slueth 2.x (POM=>Finchley.M6) working, but no avail. I have a `service1` calls `service2` and `service3`. I see that a new `traceId` is created whenever a request is received in `service1` but not passed to `Service2` and `Service3` instead a new `traceid` is being created every time on `Service2` and `Service3`.

Is this anyhow related to [this defect](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/700) ?

NOTE: I don't need zipkin support and I need sleuth for distributed tracing and will be using Splunk as log aggregater.

**Source Code**: https://github.com/trmsmy/springboot-cloud-examples/tree/springboot2

Comment: I am trying to post my example to github, will update the summary when i have it. The same example works in Spring boot 1.5.x version and spring-cloud 1.x version.

Comment: Can you try with the latest snapshots?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak So I updated to latest snapshot for both spring boot and cloud. Still the same outcome. Logs can be found here - https://gist.github.com/trmsmy/322beeb245183466b1c2b4181c7e77a4

It looks like the header X-B3-Sampled=0 is making this log "Received a request to uri [/service2] that should not be sampled [true]" and whenever this happens, the TraceID is not used from the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug that got fixed with this commit - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/commit/d7a0747907f4ab7201f67e7d0c762a324fbe0668 . Please check out the latest snapshots

Comment: This is still happening for me with feign client using the Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version of spring cloud sleuth.  If I turn on logging I see the header is not being sent and a new trace id is created for downstream service calls.  In my case though I am creating a feign client manually using "target" method on builder as per https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html